# Enable VT-x/AMD-v already but show this message when create docker-machine

Tags: docker, virtualbox, devops, docker-machine

Error with pre-create check: "This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is mandatory"

Answer (score 0):

please note that you must enable Intel or AMD Virtualization Technology in the computers BIOS in order to use VirtualBox. You must reboot your computer and then press the appropriate key, some systems use F2, others F12 or (my computer requres this) DEL key to get into the BIOS.

There are multiple guides on how to do this, Google is your friend :). Good luck!